# XML modelling tool

Tags: xml, uml, diagram

I have searched and am looking for a tool which would help when working with XML files.
I've got to understand different XML structures and it gets quite annoying when I have to draw everything on a paper or model a diagram myself.

I would like to know if anybody has some tool to offer which would help when figuring out XML structures ?

For anyone who doesn't understand why I need this, imagine this:

```
<parent id="1"> 
 <name> ... </name>
</parent>
<parent id="2">
 <name> ... </name>
</parent>

<child mother="1" father="2"></child>
```

In this case, mother and father are set by id in parent element.

And sometimes I have a huge structure which is connected with other nodes in this way(using ID or some string identificator). It sucks to handle this manually and I would like to know if there's some automatic way to draw a diagram from XML(with minimal input).

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you're asking for a tool, and you're tagging your question with UML, but perhaps you'll like the [Graph::Easy](http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/Graph-Easy-0.70/lib/Graph/Easy.pm) module with Perl, just to get a first big view of your XML.

Here is the sample XML :

```
<test>
  <parent id="1"/>
  <parent id="2"/>
  <child id="11" mother="1" father="2"/>
  <child id="10" mother="1" father="2"/>
</test>
```

Here is the little script :

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;

use Graph::Easy;
use IO::All;
use Path::Class;
use XML::LibXML;

my $graph   = Graph::Easy->new(timeout => 100);
my $parser  = XML::LibXML->new();
my $xmlFile = file('...') # Replace by your path.

my $dom = $parser->parse_file($xmlFile);
foreach my $childNode ($dom->findnodes('//child'))
{
    $graph->add_edge
    (
        $childNode->getAttribute('id'),
        $childNode->getAttribute('mother'),
        'has mother'
    );
    $graph->add_edge
    (
        $childNode->getAttribute('id'),
        $childNode->getAttribute('father'),
        'has father'
    );
}

$graph->as_svg > io("graph.svg");
```

and the result :

[image]

That's just a very simple example, but you can easily go further and add different types of lines, colors, etc. By example :

[image]

Comment: That looks something I was really looking for! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you're using the wrong tool? XML is best for identifying data stored as top-down tree structures. The structure your describing has more complex relationships (parents may in some instances be the top level element, in others the low level element)... something that a relational database (for example, SQL based) would be better at describing.

Comment: Actually I've not been using any tool for XML..

Comment: XML is good for modelling and I use it heavily to describe relationships as I don't see a point of using anything else. But the problem comes in when I am not the designer of schema but someone else. To understand someone else's structure with a lot of relationships is a pain :)

Comment: I was referring to XML itself as the tool.


From a design standpoint it would be quite a bit easier to query a relational database for the data sets you want then try and extract it from an xml sheet. The database schema itself would describe the relationships between the data and it's fairly easy to visualize with a tool like MySql Workbench. I work on a heavily XML-based project and a good set of XML parsing scripts matched with a SQLite database have become an invaluable tool for analysis.